# How to show the object array value in the each dropdown in angular 14

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, angular8, angular14

Trying to show object array value in the dropdown. I have one object and it will have 'Car', 'Bus', 'Cycle', 'MotorCycle', 'Train' array value. I want to show the value of this object in each dropdown. Like first dropdown Car array value, second dropdown Bus value, third dropdown Cycle, fourth dropdown MotorCycle value and fifth dropdown Train value. I have used input decorator. So, How to show these value in each dropdown.

main.component.ts:

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
travals = {
Car: ['Good', 'Bad'],
Bus: ['Supper', 'Coll'],
Cycle: ['Small', 'Big'],
MotorCycle: ['Too Big', 'Scooty'],
Train: ['Special', 'Nomal', 'Super Fast'],
};

vehicle = ['Car', 'Bus', 'Cycle', 'MotorCycle', 'Train']; 
constructor() {} 
ngOnInit() {}
}
```

vehicle.component.ts:

```
export class VehicleComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() data: any = []; 
constructor() {} 
ngOnInit() {
console.log(this.data);
}
}
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1w4gxt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fvehicle%2Fvehicle.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **main.component.html**

1. using **keyvalue** pipe:

```
<div
  class="custom-select"
  style="width:400px;"
  *ngFor="let vehicleType of travals | keyvalue"
>
  <p>{{ vehicleType.key }}</p>
  <app-vehicle [data]="vehicleType.value"></app-vehicle>
</div>
```

2. using hardcoded array of **vehicle**:

```
<div
  class="custom-select"
  style="width:400px;"
  *ngFor="let vehicleType of vehicle"
>
  <p>{{ vehicleType }}</p>
  <app-vehicle [data]="travals[vehicleType]"></app-vehicle>
</div>
```

Your **vehicle.component.html**:

```
<select>
  <option value="{{ val }}" *ngFor="let val of data">
    {{ val }}
  </option>
</select>
```

This should work. **keyvalue** pipe allows to iterate objects and to access key value pairs. You can use them as you like in your particular task.

Link in documentation https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe

Comment: Loading 25 times. Each dropdown loading 5 times. How to resolve this?

Comment: Not working properly: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-p6bugg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Fmain.component.html

Comment: @EMahanK see updated answer, format modified